# VSTS API - Get test category information for test run

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been looking to get hold of test results programatically, for the tests that are run during builds and releases. I am doing it via the VSTS API here.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results

The test category information, declared via [TestCategory] attribute, does not appear in this results returned by this API.

I am wondering if there is a way to get hold of test results along with category information?

The test category information is available within the downloaded test results file using the UI from within the test run details.

Is there an API endpoint that return path to the test results file (the one that can be downloaded via the UI)?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `TestCategory` from test file (such as `.trx`), you use use the REST API to [**download a test run attachment**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/attachments#download-a-test-run-attachment) instead of using the REST API to [get test result(s) from a test run](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#get-a-list-of-test-results).

You can get the test run attachment `id` firstly, and then download the attachment:

- To get the attachment id, use [the REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/attachments#get-list-of-test-run-attachments):

  ```
  GET  https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/test/runs/runId/attachments?api-version=3.0-preview
  ```

  And you can get the attachment id by the `id` parameter.
- To download the attachment, use the REST API:

  ```
  GET  https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/test/runs/runId/attachments/attachmentId?api-version=3.0-preview
  ```

  To get the `TestCategory`, you can find in the response part:

  `<TestCategory>
      <TestCategoryItem TestCategory="name" />
   </TestCategory>`